# Play HTML5 videos forward and backward on hover

Tags: html5-video

I've been trying for days to get a specific behaviour on the homepage of my personal website. But I didn't find any good solution yet. Can someone help me please :-)

I have a homepage with a grid of short videos with different durations. I want each of them to **play completely on mouse hover**. On second hover most should replay normally, **but some should play backward**.

I read that playing videos backward was not good in terms of performance because native browser players were not meant for that. So I searched for an alternative and came to the following idea:

Double the duration of those "special" videos so they integrate their forward sequence (1-2-3) and backward sequence (3-2-1) in the same file. On first hover, the video would play its first half, and after that only, on second hover it would play the second half.

Here is a **[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tacotac/v3kur075/1/)** where I put all elements for testing… but I'm currently stuck with my poor JS skills.

HTML:

```
<video class="forward-backward">
  <source src="http://tacco.fr/divers/forward-backward.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="http://tacco.fr/divers/forward-backward.webm" type="video/webm">
</video>
```

jQuery:

```
var figure = $("video").mouseover(hoverVideo);
  function hoverVideo() {
    $(this).get(0).play();
};
```

It may be a very bad idea in terms of performance (because filesizes are bigger to load), so I'm really open for any others.

Don't hesitate to ask if you have any question.
Thank you very much :-)

BTW: no more than 5 videos should play at the same time… I don't know how to do that…

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem. The best solution I can think of is to use a video editor and reverse the video files themselves. Then you create two video elements, one with the forward video as the source and one with the reverse video as the source. Using javascript, you can then show the correct video (and hide the other one) depending on whether you want the video to be playing forward or backwards. Does that help?